# Publish Failed with Instagram API

Tags: php, instagram

when I use the Instagram API to publish videos and images on my account, I always get the message

```
{
  "message" : "Sorry, there was a problem with your request.",
  "status" : "fail",
  "error_type" : "sentry_block"
}
```

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: A quick google of 'Instagram sentry_block' shows that is looks like you are getting ip blocked. Are you firing lot of concurrent requests to the service?

Comment: yes,i firing alot of requests

Comment: will the unblock be lefted soon?